# Check MySQL database for unique value over many tables

Tags: mysql

I'm looking for a way to easily check each table of a MySQL database and make sure that a certain field contains one value only. I have tables named Authors, Titles, Places, etc.

Each table contains a field called xuser and it needs to ask "does the field xuser contain the value xy in all records of all tables".

Can someone push me in the right direction how to do this with a SQL query if this is possible?

Thanks for reading, regards

Nico

Comment: Really unclear what you're asking, but it seems like you have some dara design problems (repeated data)

Comment: You want to check if `xy` exists in all three tables right? and you need that to be unique?

Comment: Sorry if that wasn't clear enough, let me try again. Each record in the database belongs to a user, each user has a unique ID. To identify the record owner each table has a field xuser. So normally we have lots of different values in xuser. For selective backup purposes we produe a dump containing only the data of one user and I want to check this dump to make sure there's only one users data in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created stored procedure which checks all table for provided db:

```
DELIMITER $$

    DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `UTL_CHECK_BACKUP_FOR_USER` $$

    CREATE PROCEDURE `UTL_CHECK_BACKUP_FOR_USER`(
                    IN i_database_name VARCHAR(255),
                    IN i_user_column_name VARCHAR(255),
                    IN i_user_column_value VARCHAR(255),
                    OUT o_result TINYINT(1)
    )
    BEGIN

        DECLARE v_table_name VARCHAR(255);
        DECLARE v_last_row_fetched TINYINT(3) DEFAULT 0;


        DECLARE tables_cursor CURSOR FOR
        SELECT table_name
        FROM information_schema.tables
        WHERE table_schema = i_database_name
        ;

        DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET v_last_row_fetched = 1;

        SET v_last_row_fetched = 0;

        OPEN tables_cursor;

        SET @query = 
            CONCAT(
                'SELECT SUM(IF(user_column=''',
                i_user_column_value,
                ''', 1, -1)) = 1 INTO @o_result FROM ( SELECT ''test'' AS user_column FROM information_schema.tables WHERE 1<>1 '
            )
        ;


        table_loop: LOOP
            FETCH tables_cursor INTO v_table_name;

            IF (v_last_row_fetched = 1) THEN
                LEAVE table_loop;
            END IF;

        SET @query = 
            CONCAT(
                @query,
                ' UNION SELECT DISTINCT(',
                i_user_column_name,
                ') AS user_column FROM ',
                v_table_name
            )
        ;


        END LOOP table_loop;

        CLOSE tables_cursor;

        SET v_last_row_fetched=0;


        SET @query = 
            CONCAT(
                @query,
                ' ) all_xusers;'
            )
        ;

        PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
        EXECUTE stmt;

        DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

        SET o_result = COALESCE(@o_result, 0);

     END $$


DELIMITER ;
```

Just deploy this stored procedure to database.
And then it could be executed in the following way:

```
-- db_name, user_column_name, user_column_value, result
call UTL_CHECK_BACKUP_FOR_USER('test', 'xuser', 'xxx', @result);
select @result;
```

Comment: What an amazing forum, thank you very much indeed for your time, effort, and helpfulness!

Answer (score 0):

To get the rows from all three tables where `xuser` has the same value in all three tables you could use:

```
 SELECT *
   FROM authors a
   JOIN titles t 
     ON t.xuser = a.xuser
   JOIN places p
     ON p.xuser = t.xuser
```

If you want to look at a specific `xuser` value you could add the following `WHERE` clause:

```
  WHERE a.xuser = 'xy'
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It doesn't really solve the problem but that's probably due to my less-then-clear initial posting

Answer (score 0):

The first thing comes to my mind:

```
select sum(if(xuser='xxx', 1, -1)) = 1 
from (
    select distinct(xuser) from authors
    union
    select distinct(xuser) from titles
    union
    select distinct(xuser) from places
) all_xusers;
```

This will return 1 (true) if all tables contains records belonging ONLY to 'xxx' user. Otherwise (if there is no 'xxx' records or there is some other user records) it will return 0 (false).

Comment: Now this is just exactly what i was looking for, thank you very much indeed. I haven't yet really understood the logic behind it but it seems very elegant to me.

Comment: So first it fetches distinct users from each table and merge them into one result set filtering out duplicates (that's what UNION does).
As result of this inner query we've got something like this: ('aaa', 'bbb', ..., 'xxx'). Of course in ideal case we should get just ('xxx').
Than using tricky IF construction we've mapped all distinct xusers to integer numbers.
If it's our user (i.e. 'xxx') we assign '1', else '-1'.
So it looks like ('aaa' => -1, 'bbb' => -1, ..., 'xxx' => 1).
And then it just sums these numbers.
If result set contains only 'xxx' record, than sum will be 1, otherwise sum<=0.

Comment: Very clever indeed and it solves my problem nicely, thank you. If I may add one further question: is it at all possible in plain SQL to achieve the same without having to name each table separately? If I would do the same in PHP or FileMaker, where I'm more at home, I would read the list of tablenames and then loop through this list, but I guess that's outside of the scope of a select statement.

Comment: In general it's possible to do this just at database level.
It could be implemented as stored procedure with iterators and dynamic sql feature.
The logic basically is the same as you've described: fetching all tables names belonging to particular db, loop throug them by apeding ' UNION select distinct(xuser) from ${table} ', and then just run generated query and return result from stored procedure.

Comment: Implemented stored procedure approach (without having to name each table), added it as a separate answer.